# Address not valid when withdrawing money from Binance

Tags: wallet, currencies, coinbase.com, withdrawal, binance

I want to withdraw the `Vibrate` crypto from binance. When I enter the `BTC` wallet address which I took from my account from `coinbase`, binance says invalid address. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3):

Note: You cannot withdraw to a bitcoin wallet as it is an entirely different network.

You would need to install a wallet that supports the so called "Vibrate" cryptocurrency, then use that to generate an address to withdraw to. I have no idea what "Vibrate" is to be honest, the closet I could find was something called "[Viberate](https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/viberate/)" which seems to be an Ethereum ERC20 token.  So, if you want to withdraw those, you need an Ethereum wallet that handles tokens.  One popular wallet is [MyEtherWallet](https://www.myetherwallet.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to withdraw an altcoin to a Bitcoin address. You need to withdraw to a ‘Vibrate’ wallet, not a Bitcoin wallet.

Comment: And where do I create a Vibrate wallet, in binance itself?

Comment: I just want the money back in simplest possible way? how can i get it?

Comment: I have no recommendation on where to create a Vibrate wallet, I would generally avoid any such altcoin myself. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can basically check the Vibrate website, usually projects post link on where to buy or store their currency. And always remember to use the BTC for BTC only, the same goes with every other coin. Except for some ETH tokens or NEO tokens, they sometimes can be sent to the coin address.